# Is there a way to capture a log of all bluetooth communication your device makes?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Let's say Bluetooth device A is an android/apple phone that communicates with Bluetooth device B a speaker. When I click "play" on a song on device A, is there a way to intercept the command that tells device B to play the song. My goal here is to possibly replicate this command.

Comment: There are multiple solution for BLE sniffers our there, one would be https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Sniffer-for-Bluetooth-LE. Keep in mind that a bluetooth speaker receives it's data via the A2DP profile of Bluetooth Classic

Answer (score 0):

For Apple Devices, you can refer to this site https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/ and install the bluetooth profile. Bear in mind that part of the requirement is that you need to have an apple developer ID (and the profile will expire in a few days. You need to reinstall if needed)

For android, I believe you can do that using bt_snoop.